# The easy way to built Google Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm totally new to chrome extension.

After try the first step of building a simple popup extension. I feel it is very difficult to build, test chrome extension.

For example, I have to

- Refresh the browser
- Click the extension button
- Test any thing inside the popup
- Right click it and check console
- I have to repeat this every time I change the codes

Is there something like the browser extension and console are opened everything i refresh browser or I can develop just like web app (in tab)?

Answer (score 0):

There are various different components in a Chrome Extension (background-/event-page, content-scripts, popup, browserAction, pageAction etc) and the process of testing may differ for each of those components.

Since you seem to be referring to a popup, you could open the corresponding HTML file in a browser tab, open the console once and then test by just reloading (e.g. hiting `F5`)  every time you make a change in the code.
<sub>Of course, not all functionality of a popup can be tested like this, but most of it can.</sub>